# How to access bitmap data of Direct2D Hardware RenderTarget?

Tags: direct2d, rendertarget

I'm using Direct2D with for some simple accelerated image compositing/manipulation, and now need to get the pixel data the RenderTarget to pass it to an encoder.

So far, I've managed this by rendering to a `BitmapRenderTarget`, then finally drawing the bitmap from that onto a `WicBitmapRenderTarget` which allows me to Lock an area and get a pointer to the pixels.

However...

This only works if my initial RenderTarget uses `D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_TYPE_SOFTWARE`, because a hardware rendertarget's bitmap can't be 'shared' with the  `WicBitmapRenderTarget` which only supports software rendering. The software rendering seems significantly slower than hardware.

Is there any way round this? Would I be better off using Direct3D instead?